# creating template/custom User Control in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

custom user control may not be the correct wording as it brings me to placing something in the toolbox. What I think I am really looking for is some option that allows me to do an add new item but instead of selecting "User Control" I would select "Menu Panel"

Say I wanted to create a new user control that I name NetworkConnectionView the code currently look like this:

```
public partial class NetworkConnectionView : UserContrl
```

however what I am hoping for is to use the "add new item" option to get a class signature that would look like this:

```
public partial class NetworkConnectionView : MenuPanel
```

The main reason for doing this is to inherit the transparency, size and other elements that are used repeatedly but also so I can have a function that has a parameter of MenuPanel. So something like this:

```
    private void InsertMenuOption(MenuPanel curMenuPanel, string name){
        curMenuPanel.Name = name
        Button menuOptionBtn = new Button()
        // initialization of menuOptionBtn parameters...
        menuOptionsPanel.controls.Add(menuOptionBtn )
        // ...
    }
```

EDIT:

based on Jimi's comment I was able to export a template however when I do an add item I am still seeing that it is inheriting directly from UserControl. With that said, it loads into my project with the expected size, backcolor etc. I am just not showing that it inherits from MenuPanel instead of UserControl.

[Image of the template that is added to the project via "Add Item"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRVgo.png)

[Image of added item signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxzPD.png)

[Desired signature then MenuPanel inherits from UserControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flLnE.png)

Comment: Maybe I didn't get your question, but why don't you just add a new class and just inherit MenuPanel, instead of adding a user control?

Comment: @NorbertForgacs I may be missing something also but when you create a user control it gives a different file structure. Namely, you have a NewUserControl.cs NewUserControl.Designer.cs and NewUserControl.resx where as in creating a new class you just get NewClass.cs

Comment: Build the `MenuPanel` UserControl, save it as Template (`Project -> Export Template -> Item Template`), so you can use it as the base class for other UserControls, inheriting `MenuPanel`. -- Saving it as Template is not necessary, but if you do, you'll find it among the other Templates in the `New Item` pane.

Comment: The standard Templates include `Inherited User Control`.

Comment: @Jimi Might have missed something however when I do the export: the template still comes in inheriting from UserControl instead of MenuPanel. I am really hoping to be able to pass a MenuPanel object instead of a Control to InsertMenuOption(...) as well as enforce size and other things. With that said, it did allow me to do an add item which was convenient and a step in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

I was way over complicating this. What I ended up needing to do was to create a "template" user control that I named MenuPanelView which inherited from user control. after setting all the desired parameters (i.e. size, transparency, etc) I then when into any object that I wanted to inherit from MenuPanelView and simply overwrote the UserControl with MenuPanelView.

So this:

```
public partial class TestUserControl : UserControl                         
{
    public TestUserControl()
    {  
         InitializeComponent();
    }                                                                          
}
```

Would just become this (and work as desired):

```
public partial class TestUserControl : MenuPanelView                         
{
    public TestUserControl()
    {  
         InitializeComponent();
    }                                                                          
}
```